# how to fit external website with iframe width

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i having problem that i can not fit the external web content exactly as per the width and height of the iframe can someone help please???

I am posting the link via form because it will be like this by posting the values.. i gave this youtube and google just for example.

External Link Form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.youtube.com" target="myFrame" >
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="pok0@3!etars16387"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="apq" value="1"/>
    <input type="image" name="apig" src="https://www.google.com/images/img.gif"/>
</form>
```

Iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="841" name="myFrame" id="myFrame">
   <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe>
```

Please help me... Thanks & Regard's

Answer (score 0):

youtube or google does not support this kind of embedding.

Try

```
"//www.youtube.com/embed/bHQqvYy5KYo"
```

instead of

```
"https://www.youtube.com"
```